# What is the use case for this zsh precommand modifier '-'

Tags: zsh

So in zsh; do this

`$ - ls /some/non/existent/directory/blah/blah/blah`

gives you

`-ls: /some/non/existent/directory/blah/blah/blah: No such file or directory`

Documentation:

http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Precommand-Modifiers

---

What reasonable use case does this actualy have?

Answer (score 3):

From `zshmisc(1)`:

```
-      The  command  is  executed  with  a `-' prepended to its argv[0]
          string.
```

Invoking a shell with a `-` prepended to its name (`-sh`, `-bash`, `-zsh`) is an old convention for indicating the shell should start a login session. It's up to the program itself to decide if such an invocation should mean anything. Most programs, like `ls`, ignore *how* they are called.